# Moving margins bug that is not activating - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a django project and I am working on a template. I have a template that has some html and css. I want to have an image that is inline with text. That is happening but I wan tot move the text down a little bit by adding padding or margin. So what i have right now is bootstrap incorporated with my html and css. I have added custom css to the template that over ride the bootstrap to get more refined css. Now what i want is to move the `| username` down a few pixels. I will have all of my code below and a sample image..

Here is my html template code:

```
<div class="row solid-borders">
  <div class=" col-md-2 border-padding">
    <img src="{% static 'images/yap-logo-possible-1.png'%}" class="header-icon-size" style="display:inline;" alt="">
    <h1 class="border-padding border-margin-top" style="display:inline;">|  {{ user.username }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my custom css that I have added:

```
.border-padding {
  padding: 8px !important;
}

.border-margin-top {
  padding-top: 25px !important;
}

.solid-borders {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

and I have bootstrap incorporated in it

sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add display:inline-block; instead of display:inline and you can move element down few pixels

```css
.border-padding {
  padding: 8px !important;
}

.border-margin-top {
  padding-top: 25px !important;
}

.solid-borders {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row solid-borders">
  <div class=" col-md-2 border-padding">
    <img src="{% static 'images/yap-logo-possible-1.png'%}" class="header-icon-size" style="display:inline-block;" alt="">
    <h1 class="border-padding border-margin-top" style="display:inline-block;">|  {{ user.username }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```